# React store and access data in state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, api, object

I'm relatively new to web development and I'm trying to brush up on my React skills. I'm attempting to make a simple weather app using the OpenWeatherMap API. I want to store the response in state so that I don't have to make multiple calls to the API.

```
      useEffect(() => {
    let API = "url";
    
    axios.get(API).then(res => {    
      setWeather(res.data);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, [])
```

I can successfully store my response in state with the above code. However, when I try to access nested data within state, React cannot find anything beyond 'data' using dot notation. Here is an example of the response I'm storing in state:

```
    {
  "lat": 33.44,
  "lon": -94.04,
  "timezone": "America/Chicago",
  "timezone_offset": -21600,
  "current": {
    "temp": 284.07,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "humidity": 62,
    "clouds": 0,
    "wind_speed": 6,
    "wind_deg": 300,
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 500,
        "main": "Rain",
        "description": "light rain",
        "icon": "10d"
      }
    ]
```

If I console.log(weatherData.current) the above code is what I get. That's great, except when I try to access 'weather' at the bottom by entering "weatherData.current.weather[0].main" the console crashes and says "cannot read properties of undefined (reading weather)."

I'm thinking that I'm not storing my API response in state correctly. I can log "weatherData.current" and I get an object back, but I can't go any deeper than that.

I'm sure I'm missing a basic step but any help is greatly appreciated. I've been searching other posts for hours and I haven't seen any other posts with this problem. I'm starting to dream in Javascript and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: You can access the 'main' weather data with `Object.values(weatherData.current.weather)[0].main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weather object is an array of objects

Example:

```
var weatherDetails = Object.values(weatherData.current.weather)[0]
```

You can then access this data with:

```
console.log(weatherDetails.main)
console.log(weatherDetails.id)
console.log(weatherDetails.description)
console.log(weatherDetails.icon)
```

If you want to use dot notation, you can store this result in it's own state:

```
setWeatherDetails(Object.values(res.data.current.weather)[0]));
```

Comment: I just tried it and got the same error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weather')"

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(Object.values(res.data.current.weather)[0]))`

Comment: Same error message. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weather')"

Edit: There was a bit I forgot to comment out. Now it's returning the weather object:

{id: 800, main: 'Clear', description: 'clear sky', icon: '01n'}
description: "clear sky"
icon: "01n"
id: 800
main: "Clear"

Comment: Your may want to store this data in it's own separate state to make it easier to access later (See edited answer)

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help. It seems I'll have to approach how I store the response a little differently. OpenWeatherMap has several different calls you can make and I was hoping to do 1 call and access the data I need. I was trying to avoid assigning a bunch of variables since it seems I may as well use vanilla js at that point. I'll play around with it. Thanks again!